# match TOKEN to shortest char sequence in javacc tokenmanager?

Tags: compiler-construction, token, javacc

according to the tokenmanager doc , it tries to match the currently seen char sequence to the longest token. I seem to run into some situations where this is not what I need:

for example in certain sql flavors,

".show table" is a statement

so I defined a token  to be ".show"

but in some regular sql, I have "select t1.show_field from t1"

here instead of giving me tokens "t1", "."  and "show_field", the token manager gave me "t1"  ".show" , while the remaining is still on the stack. this caused an error.

how can I tell javacc to parse out "." in this case? so far I separated the grammar to recognize "." "show", instead of a whole ".show". it works, but is kind of flaky.

Thanks
yang

Comment: `I separated the grammar to recognize "." "show", instead of a whole ".show"` - FWIW, that is exactly what I would do.

Comment: I assume spaces are skipped. One question is how should ".   show table" be treated.  I suppose this is what you mean by "flaky".

Answer (score 0):

You don't want that, when the remaining characters are ".show...", the next token should *always* be ".". If you did then the token ".show" would never be matched.

Equally you don't want a rule that, when the remaining characters are ".show...", the next token should *always* be ".show". Your example illustrates that.

So you need to figure out under what circumstances "." is correct and under what circumstances ".show" is correct.  The best case scenario is that you can make this depend on the lexical state.

For example, suppose that you want ".show" if it occurs at the very beginning of a command, but "." if ".show" occurs anywhere else. Then you need two lexical states. One for the first token of a command and one for the rest of the command.

See the documentation and the FAQ for more on lexical states.  In particular read the part of the FAQ that says that you should avoid trying to control the lexical state from the parser.